# как решить проблему "This Set-Cookie-header didnt specify a "SameSite"?

Tags: веб-программирование, express, cookie

ошибка: [image: полный текст ошибки]

мой контроллер:

```
    module.exports.login = (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  Users.findOne({ email })
    .select("+password")
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        return next(new ErrorLogin(errorRegistration));
      }
      return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then((matched) => {
        if (!matched) {
          return next(new ErrorLogin(errorRegistration));
        }
        const token = jwt.sign(
          { _id: user._id },
          process.env.JWT_SECRET || secretKey,
          { expiresIn: "7d" }
        );
        res.cookie("token", token, {
          secure: true,
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: "none",
        });
        return res.send({ token });
      });
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

Comment: Какая версия express?